# How Orange3 gets cosine value in Distances widget

Tags: algebra, orange

Orange3 says that cosine of No.1 vector[1, 0] to No.2 vector[0, 1] is 1.000 and No.1 to No.7 vector[-1, 0] is 2.000 in Distance Matrix as below capture. I believe that it has to be 0.000 and -1.000 because it is supposed to be cosine. Or if it is radian, it has to be 1.5708(pi/2) and 3.1415(pi).
Sounds like range of cosine is 0.0 to 2.0 in Orange3, but I've never told this before.

[image]

Does someone have any idea of this cosine results?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is cosine similarity. Orange computes [cosine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Angular_distance_and_similarity).

The code is here: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/master/Orange/distance/distance.py#L455.

Comment: Yes, I mean that its cosine similarity. I thought that Orange will give it since the 'Help' says that it it angle. I checked if the result of (1.0 - sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(arr)) becomes cosine distance from Orange as your Wikipedia's definition. And it becomes the same value. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're right, this should be corrected, thanks. I opened an issue on github, https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/5587. You're welcome to do so next time you encounter a similar problem.